# "Import" ES6 for Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I want to use import from ES6 rather than require from common.js in Node.
For some reason I thought import would work by default in Node. But looks like it does not. Is there some npm package i need to install for that to work?

Comment: If you're using pure node js, that is ES5. You'll need babel or io.js to get ES6 features.

Comment: I have version 0.12.4 of node. I tried es6-module-loader but did not work. I shall try babel and io

Comment: `io.js` doesn't have native support for ES6 modules either, and `Babel` is going to use `System.js` which uses `es6-module-loader` at it's core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js does not currently support ES6 modules natively. You'd need to use a separate package to implement this behavior.

The de-facto standard would be [es6-module-loader](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader), which works in the browser as well as in a Node environment.

`Babel.js` uses `System.js`, which uses `es6-module-loader` at it's core. If it didn't work for you, it's likely an issue with your implementation.

Comment: my intellisense is telling me import is ES6 feature your current language level is ES5. How do I change my current language level. Now I have both babel and es6-module-loader. I guess I just need one of them. But not good enough to make my node es6

Comment: `Node.js` and `io.js` both support *some* ES6 features, but ES6 modules are not one of those features. I'm not even sure it's implemented in the V8 engine yet. What does exist is a spec, or syntax for how it should work. `es6-module-loader` implements that syntax.

You can use ES6 in `Node.js` using the `--harmony` flag, and in `io.js`, but that doesn't include ES6 modules.

Comment: I am new to babel, so I might be not doing it right. I have "build": "rm -rf lib && babel src --out-dir lib" in packages.json. I do not know how you invoke that? i am guessing using npm build?

Comment: Yes, if run `npm build` it should run whatever command you've entered as the value for `build` in `package.json`

Comment: So when I run it like that it gives me no output. I am guessing it ran. But i was expecting some sort of output from it. Btw  you do not need to install babel outside your project to do this right? Just having babel module installed in your project is good enough to transpile your lib folder? Cuz If I look at my command it is trying to run babel from command line. But if I just type babel it is not recognized command on my system.

Comment: You'll need to install the Babel CLI globally for it to work. `npm install -g babel`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 for your Node.js files, but you should transpile them into ES5 like with React.js Components.

Probably any code, you want to be written with ES6 you must transpile into ES5 using babel.

Take a look on my ["MERN Heroku starter kit"](https://github.com/Naterra/MERN-Heroku-Starter-Kit)

Answer (score -6):

With node you can pass an --harmony flag that enable some ES6 feature:

```
node index.js --harmony
```

But I'm not sure that import are between those features. I really suggest to use babel that compiles es6 to es5 and it's really complete, Facebook is now using babel for React instead of their own transpiler and you can also use some cool ES7 features like await/async

Comment: `import` and ES6 modules are not a part of the ES6 implementation of Node.js