# ES6 modules syntax support on IBM bluemix

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, ibm-cloud, devops, es6-modules

I have an app that uses ES6 import statements. I try to deploy it on ibm cloudfoundry. The logs shows that it starts with node 6.8.0. The app complains :

```
 Unexpected token import
```

I started the app on my windows 10 desktop, with node 6.8.0 and it runs flawlessly. I ran :

```
console.log(process.versions);
```

Here is the output :

```
{ http_parser: '2.7.0',
  node: '6.8.0',
  v8: '5.1.281.84',
  uv: '1.9.1',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  icu: '57.1',
  modules: '48',
  openssl: '1.0.2j' }
```

Output is same on my machine where app works and on the bluemix server where it doesn't. Here my Package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "bluemixtest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "server/app.js",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --harmony_modules server/app.js"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

server/app.js:

```
'use strict';
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
```

Startup error in logs :

```
/home/vcap/app/server/app.js:7
import express from 'express';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-33-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! bluemixtest@0.0.0 start: `node --harmony server/app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bluemixtest@0.0.0 start script 'node --harmony server/app.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bluemixtest package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the es6 standard defines the import statement, it is not supported by node natively (yet). ["Import" ES6 for Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878363/import-es6-for-node)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: This is my code in server/index.js I commented the if statement which might have been the culprit!//if (env === 'development' || env === 'test') {
  // Register the Babel require hook
  require('babel-register');
//}

Comment: `//if (env === 'development' || env === 'test') {
  // Register the Babel require hook
  require('babel-register');
//}`